# How to replace backup file with timestamp in its name without producing duplicates in Linux Bash (shell script)

Tags: linux, bash, shell, cron

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# usage: wttr [location], e.g. wttr Berlin, wttr New\ York

# Standard location if no parameters were passed
location=''
language=''
time=`date`
# Expand terminal display


if [ -z "$language" ]; then
  language=${LANG%_*}
fi

curl \
     -H -x "Accept-Language: ${language}" \
     -x wttr.in/"${1:-${location}}" |
head -n 7 |
tee /home/of/weather.txt |
tee -a /home/of/weather.log |
tee /home/of/BACKUP/weather_"$time".txt

#cp weather.txt /home/of/BACKUP
#mv -f /home/of/BACKUP/weather.txt /home/of/BACKUP/weather_"$time".txt
```

I'm very new to Linux Bash and Shell scripting and can't figure out the following.
I have a problem with the shell script above.
It works fine so far (curling ASCII data from website and writing it to `weather.txt` and `.log`).
It is also in set in crontab to run every 5 minutes.
Now I need to make a backup of `weather.txt` under `/home/of/`, in `/home/of/BACKUP` with the filename `weather_<timestamp>.txt`.
I tried to delete (`rm weather*.txt`) the old timestamped files in `/home/of/BACKUP` and then copy and rename the file everytime the cronjob is running.
I tried piping `cp` and `mv` and so on but somehow I end up with producing many duplicates as due to the timestamp the filenames are different or nothing at all when I try to delete the content of the folder first.
All I need is ONE backup file of `weather.txt` as `weather_<timestamp>.txt` which gets updated every 5 minutes with the actual timestamp bit I can't figure it out.

Comment: As an aside, `tee` can write to multiple files, though you need two invocations if only some of them should have the `-a` option. If you expect the other files to not already exist, you can `tee -a /home/of/weather.txt /home/of/weather.log /home/of/BACKUP/weather_"$time".txt`

Comment: Only weather.log should have appended data the others should be overwritten every time :)

Comment: Then `tee those two | tee -a third`

Comment: I don't understand your question. Does removing `BACKUP/weather_*.txt` and then copying in the new file with the new name not work?

Comment: Unfortunately not, the problem does not occur if I manually execute the script, via cron job I get an empty BACKUP folder

Comment: Which problem though? We don't really need to see your `curl` code but the actual code which you are asking about, i.e. just the backup part, ideally with a couple of attempts and an explanation of why those didn't work. See also the guidance for providing a [mre].

Comment: Well that's what was commented out at the end. This works if I start it manually but not via crontab  rm /home/of/BACKUP/weather*.txt
cp weather.txt /home/of/BACKUP
mv  /home/of/BACKUP/weather.txt /home/of/BACKUP/weather_"$time".txt

Comment: Piping `mv` to `cp` sounds alarmingly wrong, `mv` doesn't print anything and `cp` doesn't read anything. A pipe like `echo moo | nl` feeds the output from `echo` as input to `nl`

Comment: Your `cp` looks for `weather.txt` in the current directory, whereas all your other commands use a full path. We can't know in which directory you are running these commands; if they are in the `cron` of `of` then they will run in `/home/of` but if not, that's the problem.

Comment: They are in the users cron that's why I don't get it but I'll try it with a full path, thank you

Comment: There's no `rm` command that I can see in the script, and the answer primarily adds the `rm` command. I don't see how this will be helpful to other/future users on this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question at all, then simply

```
rm -f /home/of/BACKUP/weather_*.txt
cp /home/of/weather.txt /home/of/BACKUP/weather_"$time".txt
```

`cp` lets you rename the file you are copying to; it doesn't make sense to separately `cp` and then `mv`.

For convenience, you might want to `cd /home/of` so you don't have to spell out the full paths, or put them in a variable.

```
dir=/home/of
rm -f "$dir"/BACKUP/weather_*.txt
cp "$dir"/weather.txt "$dir"/BACKUP/weather_"$time".txt
```

If you are running out of the `cron` of the user named `of` then your current working directory will be `/home/of` (though if you need to be able to run the script manually from anywhere, that cannot be guaranteed).

Obviously, make sure the wildcard doesn't match any files you actually want to keep.

As an aside, you can simplify the `tee` commands slightly. If this should only update the files and not print anything to the terminal, you could even go with

```
curl \
     -H -x "Accept-Language: ${language}" \
     -x wttr.in/"${1:-${location}}" |
head -n 7 |
tee /home/of/weather.txt \
    >>/home/of/weather.log
```

I took out the `tee` to the backup file since you are deleting it immediately after anyway. You could alternatively empty the backup directory first, but then you will have no backups if the `curl` fails.

If you want to keep printing to the terminal, too, probably run the script with redirection to `/dev/null` in the `cron` job to avoid having your email inbox fill up with unread copies of the output.